# Automapper ignores the ignore property for nested object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have an Order object that has a list of OrderLine objects and an OrderVm object that has a list of OrderLineVm objects.  The OrderLine object has a ValueB field that does not exist in the OrderLineVm object.

**The problem I have is that ValueB gets set to null by AutoMapper even though I tell it to ignore this property:**

```
[TestFixture]
public class AutomapperDestinationIssueTest2
{
    [Test]
    public void OrderLineValueBShouldNotBeNull()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<OrderVm, Order>().ForMember(dest => dest.Lines, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());
        Mapper.CreateMap<OrderLineVm, OrderLine>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ValueB, opts => opts.Ignore());

        var orderVm = new OrderVm() { Id = 1 };
        orderVm.Lines.Add(new OrderLineVm() { ValueA = "New ValueA"} );
        var order = new Order() { Id = 1 };
        order.Lines.Add(new OrderLine() { ValueA = "Old ValueA", ValueB = "Old ValueB " });

        Mapper.Map(orderVm, order);
        Assert.IsNotNull(order.Lines[0].ValueB); // Fails.  ValueB is null here.
    }

    public class OrderLine
    {
        public string ValueA { get; set; }
        public string ValueB { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrderLineVm
    {
        public string ValueA { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<OrderLine> Lines { get; set; }

        public Order()
        {
            Lines = new List<OrderLine>();
        }
    }

    public class OrderVm
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<OrderLineVm> Lines { get; set; }
        public OrderVm()
        {
            Lines = new List<OrderLineVm>();
        }
    }
}
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Not necessarily an ignore, but maybe this question will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439132/automapper-not-ignoring-nested-property?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an additional mapping to your map creation, the map from list to list and it starts working.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderVm, Order> ().ForMember(dest => dest.Lines, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());
Mapper.CreateMap<List<OrderLineVm>,List<OrderLine>> ();
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderLineVm, OrderLine> ().ForMember (d => d.ValueB, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Comment: Just a note - by default on collections, AutoMapper will clear them out beforehand. With this method, AutoMapper does not.